# Android unable to POST data to WCF service

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, rest

I am trying to POST data to my database using WCF service, the web service do not seems to be working, could anyone fix it for me?

**Here is my code:**

**WCF Service .cs:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAllocationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "StrongestWifi",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void UpdateStrongestWifi(myWifiClass myWifiClass);

}

[DataContract]
public class myWifiClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Time")]
    public string Time
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "SignalStrength")]
    public string SignalStrength
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "SSID")]
    public string SSID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

** WCF Service .svc**

```
    public void UpdateStrongestWifi(myWifiClass myWifiClass)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PCSDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TestingTable (Time,SignalStrength,SSID) Values (@Time,@SignalStrength,@SSID)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", myWifiClass.Time);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignalStrength", int.Parse(myWifiClass.SignalStrength));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSID", myWifiClass.SSID);

            int queryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

**Android Code:**

```
private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/StrongestWifi");
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JSONStringer getWifiInfo;
        try {
            getWifiInfo = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                    .key("myWifiClass")
                        .object()
                            .key("Time").value("TIME")                                  
                            .key("SignalStrength").value("Strength")
                            .key("SSID").value("ID")
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getWifiInfo.toString());

        request.setEntity(entity);

        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          textDisplay.setText("Success");
    }
}
```

**Log Cat:**

```
>06-01 21:02:20.150: D/WebInvoke(2832): Saving : 400
```

Comment: are you getting any error? what you are showing is a Log cat entry made by you not a error

Comment: i did not get any errors, that was the only thing that came out when i clicked the button

Comment: ok what values are you sending if you don't get any error that means your code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution, was sending SignalStrength in String format instead of int